# SwiftUI view does not update when FetchRequest data changes from inside Action Extension

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm sharing a Core Data store with my action extension, which adds data to it. My app has a SwiftUI view that presents this data, fetched with a `FetchRequest`:

```
private struct VideosScrollView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    private var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Video>

    init(sortOrder: String, tagIds: String, showWatched: Bool) {
        fetchRequest = Video.getFetchRequest(sortingBy: "addDate",
                                             with: sortOrder,
                                             showWatched: showWatched,
                                             tagIds: tagIds)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            if fetchRequest.wrappedValue.isEmpty {
                ContentEmptyView()
            } else {
                ForEach(fetchRequest.wrappedValue) { item in
                    VideoCellView(video: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After adding data from the action extension and going back to the app, the view is not updated. Only after CloudKit finished a sync is that the view notices something changed and updates itself.

How can I force my SwiftUI view to update when data changes in the action extension?

Comment: Do they share the core data url using appgroup? Also you should wrap the FerchRequest with @

Comment: They do share the same Core Data store via an App Group. I'm not using @FetchRequest because I initialize it in my struct's `init` function. This setup works as expected when adding a new item from the main app. The issue happens only when I add it from the action extension.